# Необходимо проверить матрицу на отсутствие в ней соседних в одной строке единиц и, если таковые обнаружатся сразу прервать обход матрицы циклами

Tags: c#

```
        //Не знаю как можно прервать все циклы сразу после обнаружения соседних единиц :(

        int[,] cinema = new int[5, 6] {
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }};


        for ( int i = 0; i < cinema.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < cinema.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                bool checkRule = (cinema[i, j] == 1 && cinema[i, j + 1] == 1 ? true : false);
                if (checkRule)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Нарушение!");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Можно вынести переменную checkRule за границы циклов (перед циклами например) и проверять ее в обоих циклах. Ну или можно тупо return сделать, то есть выйти из всей функции, у вас же после циклов кода нет все равно.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, проблема решена)

Comment: `throw new Exception("Нарушение!");`

Comment: рассаживание людей в кинотеатре при короновирусе, ха, по-правде актуально